# JavaScript async vs C# async

Tags: javascript, c#, asynchronous, concurrency

**EDIT**: found the answer - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

_

Okay, so I have some C# background and C# "async environment" is a bit of a mixed bag of concurrency and "[small parallelism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)" i.e. when it comes to heavy async environment you ***can*** have race conditions, deadlock and you need to protect shared resources.

Now, I'm trying to understand how does JavaScript/ES6 async environment works. Consider following code:

```js
// current context: background "page"
// independent from content page
let busy = false;

// This is an event handler that receives event from content page
// It can happen at any time
runtimeObj.onMessage.addListener((request) =>
{
    if(request.action === 'AddEntry')
    {
        AddEntry(request);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
} );


function AddEntry(data)
{
    if (!busy)
        group.push({url: data.url, time: Date.now(), session: data.session});
    else
        setTimeout(AddEntry(data),10000) // simulating Semaphore wait
}

// called from asynchronous function setInterval()
function SendPOST()
{
    if (groups.length < 1 || groups === undefined)
        return;

    busy = true; // JS has no semaphores so I "simulate it"
    let del = [];
    groups.forEach(item =>
    {
        if (Date.now() - item.time > 3600000)
        {
            del.push(item);
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            let data = new FormData();
            data.append('action', 'leave');
            data.append('sessionID', item.session);
            xhr.withCredentials = true;
            http.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status !== 200) {
                    console.log(`Unable to part group ${item.url}! Reason: ${http.status}. Leave group manually.`)
            }
}
            xhr.open('POST', item.url, true);
            xhr.send(data);
        }
    });
    del.forEach(item => groups.slice(item,1));
    busy = false;
}


setInterval(SendPOST, 60000);
```

This is not really the best example, since it does not have bunch of async keyword paired with functions but in my understanding both `sendPost()` and `AddEntry()` arent really pure sequential operations. Nonetheless, I've been told that in `AddEntry()`, `busy` always will be `false` because:

> sendPost is queued to execute in a minute
>
> an event is add to the event loop
>
> the event is processed and AddEntry is called
>
> since busy = false the group is pushed
>
> a minute passes and SendPost is added to the event loop
>
> the event is process and SendPost is called
>
> groups.length === 1 so it continues
>
> busy = true
>
> each group causes a request to get queued
>
> an event comes in
>
> busy = false
>
> the event is processed, AddEntry is called
>
> busy is false, like it will always be
>
> group is pushed
>
> eventually the requests from before are resolved, and t
>   he onreadystatechange callbacks are put on the event loop
>
> eventually each of the callbacks are processed and the logging statements are executed

Is this correct? From what I understand it essentially means there can be no race conditions or deadlock or I ever need to protect shared resource.

If I'm two write a *similar code* for C# runtime where `sendPost()` and `AddEntry()` are asynchronous task methods that can be called in non-blocking way from different event sources there **could** situation when I access shared resource while the iteration context is temporally suspended in context switch by Thread Sheduler.

Comment: This: _Is this correct? From what I understand it essentially means there can be no race conditions or deadlock or I ever need to protect shared resource._ Yes - it is called "_Run to Completion_" in JavaScript. Logic errors can create race conditions where a dev expects something to be set prior to completion, but that is due to a code problem - not a concurrency problem.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: @RandyCasburn Yes, that is what essentially the `quoted text` in my post explains.

Comment: As I suspected, just wanted to make sure. @jonas has a terrific answer for you.

Comment: You should switch this: `groups.length < 1 || groups === undefined` into this `!groups || groups.length < 1` the former might throw an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this correct?

Yes, it describes adequately whats happening.

JS runs in a single threaded way, which means that a function will always run till it's end.

```
 setTimeout(function concurrently() {
   console.log("this will never run");
 });

  while(true) console.log("because this is blocking the only thread JS has");
```

> there can be no race conditions ...

There can (in a logical way). However, they cannot appear in synchronous code, as JavaScript runs single threaded¹. If you add a callback to something, or `await` a promise, then other code might run in the *meantime* (but never *at the same time!*), which might cause a race condition:

```
 let block = false;

 async function run() {
   if(block) return // only run this once
   // If we'd do block = true here, this would be totally safe
   await Promise.resolve(); // things might get out of track here
   block = true;
   console.log("whats going on?");
}

run(); run();
```

> ... nor deadlocks ...

Yes, they are quite impossible (except if you use Atomics¹).

> I never need to protect shared resource.

Yes. Because there are no shared ressources (okay, except SharedBuffers¹).

---

¹: By using WebWorkers (or threads on NodeJS), you actually control multiple JS threads. However each thread runs its own JS code, so variables are not shared. These threads can pass messages between each other and they can also share a specific memory construct (a [SharedArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer)). That can then be accessed concurrently, and all the effects of concurrent access apply (but you will rarely use it, so ...).

Comment: "Because there are no shared ressources[...]" /// how come? The `groups` array in my code *supposedly* a shared collection. i say supposedly because I thought `AddEntry()` can execute any time, even during the moment when `sendPOST()` iterates through it because `AddEntry()` **is** a callback, technically. Also, the code example you provided makes no sense, you made erroneous lock on purpose, you do not use lock that way. I'm talking about race condition due to concurrency when no locks used.

Comment: @Kirikan what is your definition of "shared resource" (in context of thread safety)? Since regular JavaScript is singlethreaded (as Jonas Wilms mentioned in the answer) there is no "shared resources" if regular thread safety meaning (resource accessed by multiple thread)...

Comment: @Kirikan there are no locks in code in the answer - could you please clarify what you mean "you made erroneous lock on purpose"? (again - locks make no sense for single-threaded environment)

Comment: @kirikan no. No code will run at the same time. Yes `AddEntry` is a callback. That means that code might run in the mea time *before* it was called and *after it finished*, but the function itself does only run if no other code is executing.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov So how async queries are handled? Doesnt JS VM uses context switching too? In this case you dont need multiple threads, if context switches during your iteration process and then processes the AddEntry code you get the similar situation that can happen in C# async environment even with a single thread.

Comment: @kirikan no. There are no threads. Forget about everything you've learnt with C#.

Comment: @JonasWilms actually C# and JS are very similar in a way "async" works - both schedule completion callback (with the portion of a method after `await`) on proper thread - which in many cases on C# is UI thread and in JS is *the only* thread. (whether it is helpful or not - open question)

Comment: @Kirikan there is no "context switching" in JavaScript. All code runs till completion synchronously and only after that engine will pick next piece of code to run synchronously. "Next piece" is either top level code (next JS file) or next callback (external like click/http response or timer). `await`/`async` is just nice syntax for constructing callback on promise resolution (which is itself just wrapper around callbacks).

Comment: @alexeiLenkov I just read through the C# docs, and I agree that Promises and Tasks are quite similar. However as they are both "just wrappers for callbacks", and callbacks behave quite differently in C# and JS, it is still difficult to compare them.

Comment: Javascript callback will run only when call stack is empty. Where as c# callback will run immediately. Is this a valid difference?